# Year over year running month total percentage change in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I've been struggling with this for a while. I need to calculate running month total percentage change year over year. I got it working but its not getting the running total for the month to do the calculation. By the way this is on the graph. Here are my calculations below:

[how graph looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FZx1.jpg)

[image]

```
ImprovementIncidentPercentage = 1 - DIVIDE([CurrYearIncidents],[LastYearIncidents],0)
 
CurrYearIncidents = CALCULATE(count(VW_RI_INCIDENTONLY_PBI[Incident]),
Filter(VW_RI_INCIDENTONLY_PBI,VW_RI_INCIDENTONLY_PBI[EVENTDATE].[Year] =('newsecondyear'[SecondYearValue])))

 
LastYearIncidents = CALCULATE(count(VW_RI_INCIDENTONLY_PBI[Incident]),
Filter(VW_RI_INCIDENTONLY_PBI,VW_RI_INCIDENTONLY_PBI[EVENTDATE].[Year] = 'newfirstyear'[FirstYearValue]))
```

The second and first year value is used as slicers for them to be able to pick two years they want to see the percentage improvement on:

[slicers to pick what two years to do percent improvement on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPKJP.jpg)
I know something has to change CurrYearIncidents and LastYearIncidents so it does the calculation for running total for the month not the monthly total. I am just not sure how to make it work. Here is the close look at the issue.

[show as table graph of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J32QP.jpg)
For January the calculation is correct 1-(10/14) = 28.6%
For February it should be 1-(30/29) but instead it does monthly total for february and doesn't add up january so it does 1-(20/15)
To get accumulation values month over month I use this measure:
Cumulative events = TOTALYTD ( count (VW_RI_INCIDENTONLY_PBI[INCIDENT]), VW_RI_INCIDENTONLY_PBI[EVENTDATE].[Date])

Please help!

Comment: your formula is not calculating running total that is the reason, Can you add sample data?

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: Can you add sample data?